# NSSliderCell and NSButtonCell won't change values

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nscell

I have an NSTableView with an NSTableColumn whose value is bound to that of an NSArrayController. I am using a delegate to give which rows have which cell types. When, in the .nib file, the column's cell is an NSTextFieldCell, then the NSSliderCell and NSButtonCell checkboxes won't change value (as in I can click the check box and move the slider, but when I release the mouse, the values revert). When I change the cell type (in the nib file) to an NSActionCell, the NSButtonCell and the NSSliderCell work correctly, but I am unable to edit the NSTextFieldCell. When I use the `- [NSTableView editColumn:row:withEvent:select:]`to force the cell to be edited, when I submit the value it reverts to the original value, just like with the NSSliderCell and the NSButtonCell. I have tried subclassing the NSTableColumn and overriding the dataCellForRow: method, which produced the same results. When I disconnect all of the bindings on the NSTableColumn, the same result occurs (except of course, the cells are all blank).

Do you guys have any ideas as to how to solve this?

Thanks.